# splitting a stream

Tags: c#, filestream

how to split a stream  in to requires size, i need to send it in a sockets to another system,then i need to append them and create a FILE

Answer (score 1):

Since it is by byte array, you could send it by chunk. You must create 3 methods. The first will accept the total byte count and might return an id or filename (of the temporary file) where the current uploaded data is stored. 2nd method is use to upload chunks of data (that is recognized by id, filename). 3rd will inform that the process is completed (based on id, filename).

When the 3rd process is completed you could do your stuff then (like save it to database, etc.)